# How to call a python function with arguments in django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

How do I call a function with arguments in template? Is there any way to do something like?

```
{% function(args) %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. It's called [custom template filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters)

> Custom filters are just Python functions that take one or two arguments:
>
> - The value of the variable (input) – not necessarily a string.
> - The value of the argument – this can have a default value, or be left out altogether.
>
> For example, in the filter {{ var|foo:"bar" }}, the filter foo would be passed the variable var and the argument "bar".

Answer (score -2):

In your urls you have something like function.name.

You will call something like this: {% function.name parameter %}